# Set QTreeView to QVariantMap content

Tags: qt

Is there an automatic method that i can use to set the content of QVariantMap to the QTreeView, or i have to define a model for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want your map to serve as the data source or is it just a temporary container? You can use a standard model and load data into it...But if you want to use the map directly then you have to wrap it into a model.

Comment: I simply want to show the data in my map into the tree view

Answer (score 0):

Please excuse the fact that I have to provide my example in python (PyQt4). There are two ways to approach your solution. You can either just push your QVariantMap data into a model that is connected to your views, which you manage independently, or, you would have to define your own model that wraps around a QVariantModel as a data source to actively drive the data.

I am providing a simple example of pushing your data into a standard model. There is no QVariantMap in python, so I am using a dictionary of key int's => QVariant string values.

```
class View(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(View,self).__init__()

        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.table = QtGui.QTableView()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.table)

        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton("Update")
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)

        # Using a normal QStandardItemModel and setting
        # it on the table view.
        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)
        self.table.setModel(self.model)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.populate)

    def populate(self):
        # no QVariantMap in PyQt4. Creating a dictionary on the fly
        # of int key => QVariant string...  {0: QVariant('foo'), ...}
        variantMap = {i:QtCore.QVariant('foo') for i in xrange(10)}

        col = 0
        row = 0
        # loop over each element in your map, and add a QStandardItem
        # at a specific row/column
        for name, val in variantMap.iteritems():
            item = QtGui.QStandardItem(val.toString())
            self.model.setItem(row, col, item)
            row += 1
```

I create a QTableView, and a QStandardItemModel. Then I set the model on the view. I create a button that connects to a populate slot. When this slot is called, I create a "QVariantMap" type object on the fly to simulate your data container. Then I loop over the contents of that container, and create a `QStandardItem` for each cell. I set the item into the model at a specific column and row. In this example I am just using the column 0, and appending rows.

I hope this example translates easily to your situation.